# Modulus warning: The output directory is under your source tree

Tags: meteor, modulus.io

When I run `modulus deploy` with a Meteor app, it prints to the console `WARNING: The output directory is under your source tree.`

What does this warning mean?

Comment: do you have android / iOS added to your project as platform?

Comment: No, I don't. No platforms in addition to the website.

Comment: If you want, you can share code with me and I will give it a try on my side.